# JPQL query that returns entities involving a many to many relationship

Tags: java, jpa, many-to-many, jpql, named-query

I need a JPQL query that returns:

- All Tweets that I posted
- All Tweets that are posted by users whom I follow (this is the many to many part)

I tried something like:

```
SELECT t
FROM Tweet t
WHERE t.author.id = :userId
OR t.author.id IN (
    SELECT u.followedUsers
    FROM User u
    WHERE u.id = :userId
)
```

Only to find out that the subquery has [wrong syntax](https://snag.gy/gmLAp2.jpg). Also I cannot call the relation table User_User, like I would in SQL, because JPA doens't recognize it

**User**

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "followedUsers")
    private Set<User> followers;

    @ManyToMany
    private Set<User> followedUsers;

}
```

**Tweet**

```
@Entity
public class Tweet {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne
    private User author;

}
```

Comment: Suggest that you look at something more like `t.author MEMBER OF {collection field}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the habit of making JPQL queries more similar to SQL queries. So, my suggestion:

```
SELECT t FROM Tweet t
JOIN t.author a
WHERE a.id = :idUser
OR a.id IN (SELECT followedUser.id 
    FROM User u
    JOIN u.followedUsers followedUser
    WHERE u.id = :idUser)
```

Comment: I didn't think about joining those tables, because, you know, JPA mostly handles relations between entities. Your answer keeps the query very readable, which is nice. This approach also works.

Answer (score 0):

given this query

```
OR t.author.id IN (
            SELECT u.followedUsers
            FROM User u
            WHERE u.id = :userId
        )
```

you are trying to find an Integer `(t.author.id)` in a list of `User` objects !
I think this should work :

```
 SELECT t
    FROM Tweet t
    WHERE t.author.id = :userId
    OR t.author MEMBER OF (
        SELECT u.followedUsers
        FROM User u
        WHERE u.id = :userId
    )
```

---

**Edit**

`... MEMBER OF (subquery)...` isn't allowed, but merging the subquery into its parent resolves this.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(t)
FROM Tweet t, User u
WHERE t.author.id = :userId
OR (t.author MEMBER OF u.followedUsers AND u.id = :userId)
```

Comment: True, I compared integers to users. It should've been either `t.author.id IN :collectionOfIntegers` or `t.author MEMBER OF :collectionOfUsers`.
Both of these examples work by the way, but then I'd have to know who I am following and send another query beforehand.

Your guess `... MEMBER OF (SELECT...` gives a [compilation error](https://snag.gy/ZkTiNy.jpg), but you're close. JPQL did not accept a subquery there, so I tried to merge it.

`SELECT DISTINCT(t) FROM Tweet t, User u WHERE t.author.id = :userId OR (t.author MEMBER OF u.followedUsers AND u.id = :userId)`
This did it for me!